# Is there any relation between convolution performed by a kernel and transpose of the kernel on same image

Tags: image-processing, matrix, computer-vision, signal-processing, convolution

I have a MxN matrix and PxQ kernel. I am performing the simple convolution using 4 loops. I am handling border cases separately by replication the image border data.

I need to perform the convolution on same image using the kernel PxQ and its transpose QxP. Then I have to do simple addition of the two output images.

The problem is that it is taking much time and I need to optimize this. Separating the kernel and performing 1D convolution seems difficult as both the image and kernel are non squire matrices. Also I can not use any library. The kernel is completely random and is not of any predefined type.

So I want to know that is there any relation in convolution performed using a kernel and then using its transpose on same image which I can utilize.

Or is there anything else which I can do?

Comment: If you used FFT to calculate the convolution, you could save one FFT.

Comment: But according to FFT theory, it will give gain if the convolution kernel is more that 64 points. What if the kernel is smaller e.g. 5x5, 8x6 etc ??

Comment: I would trust no theory that makes such claims. If you compare different FFT implementation (the same for convolutions), the fastest will probably be at least an order of magnitude faster than the slowest. Write your own implementation, and it's going to be 10 times slower still (and I'm not talking about GPU implementations!). They might all perform the same arithmetic operations, but on modern CPUs with SIMD, branch prediction, multiple cache levels and multiple execution pipelines per thread, that means very little.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is indeed a relation, but it's a mathematical one and both convolution operators are said to be *adjoint*.

However, given non-separable convolution kernels, you have only a few options to speed-up your computations:

- as suggested in the comments, you have convolution by point-wise [multiplication of Fourier transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) of the data and the convolution kernel. Of course, you need an FFT routine to make this a viable option;
- if *P* and *Q* are not too different, you can implement a routine that will compute both convolutions and their summed output during the same pas over the image data
- you can get minor speed-up by implementing carefully the sliding window displacement during thd convolution (the first and last columns are the only things that change when moving from one pixel to its immediate neighbour).
- you can also get some speed-up by porting your convolution to the GPU if one is available. Google for example for "opencl convolution example".

For the sliding window, suppose that you have computed the output for the datapoint `d(i)` in 1D. Then, when moving to point `d(i+1)`, you can compute it by removing `kernel(-P/2)*d(i-P/2)` and adding `kernel(P/2)*d(i+P/2)` to the filitered point corresponding to `d(i)` instead of applying the whole convolution kernel.

To apply both kernels at the same time, resize the smaller kernel to the size of the bigger one by padding it with zeros and convolve your image with both kernels at the same time. This is assuming that both kernels are applied to the same input, although a common case is that the adjoint is applied *after* the regular operator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not have GPU support or threading. Also FFT will do well for more than 64 point. I did not get your 2nd and 3rd point well. Can you please elaborate a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I have to do simple addition of the two output images.

Why don't you just add the two kernels, then convolve only once with the sum?